# javascript function returning string incorrectly in html

Tags: javascript

in js file i wrote function to return string and calling this function is script tag inside HTML file

```
function getExp()
{
    var exp = "]]><!\\[CDATA\\[";
    return exp;
}
```

but its returning

```
]><!\[CDATA\[
```

what is the issue why string is not returned by function as it is ?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using '\' (escape key) in your string so it's ignoring the text to the right of that. try this instead.

```
var exp = "]]><!\\\\[CDATA\\\\["
```

Comment: no success i tried this and what abt starting 2 rectangular closing brackets

Comment: If that doesn't work there is another issue with your code. exp is correct. Try running it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getExp()
{
   var exp = "\]]><!\\\\[CDATA\\\\[";
   return exp;
}
```

Its return

```
 ]]><!\\[CDATA\\[
```